# Line break in arabic text?

Tags: line-breaking, arabic, arabtex

i'm stuck trying to insert a line break in an arabic text, any suggestions are welcome

I'm using `\usepackage{arabtex}`
Here is the complete example

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}  % caption must be loaded before arabtex
\usepackage{utf8}

\begin{document}
 \setcode{utf8}

\begin{large}
\RL{
خلال الأربعينات، مع تطوير آلات حاسبة أكثر قوة وقدرة حسابية، تتطور مصطلح \LR{\\}حاسوب ليشير إلى الآلات بدلا من الأشخاص الذين يقومون بالحسابات. وأصبح من الواضح أن الحواسيب يمكنها أن تقوم بأكثر من مجرد عمليات حسابية وبالتالي انتقلوا لدراسة تحسيب أو التحسيب بشكل عام. ب
}
\end{large}
\end{document}
```

thanks

Comment: can you please add a minimal example of your code

Comment: @touhami i updated the question

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution, one can use `\\`, `\par` or blanck line. `\noindent` works fine inside `arabtext` environment

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}  % caption must be loaded before arabtex
\usepackage{utf8}

\begin{document}
\setcode{utf8}

\begin{arabtext}
\large
خلال الأربعينات، مع تطوير آلات حاسبة أكثر قوة وقدرة حسابية، \\
تتطور مصطلح
حاسوب ليشير إلى الآلات بدلا من الأشخاص الذين يقومون بالحسابات. 

وأصبح من الواضح أن الحواسيب يمكنها أن تقوم بأكثر من مجرد عمليات حسابية وبالتالي انتقلوا لدراسة تحسيب أو التحسيب بشكل عام. ب
\end{arabtext}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nothing of the solutions worked ... have you really tested your solution ... i'm using texMaker on windows 7

Comment: @Frankenstein i am not sure i understand your comment, but the solution is tested under windows 7 (texmaker) and using online compiler and editors.

Comment: i means that i have tried \\ , \par, \noindent  but i got an error 'undefined control sequence' \test@command ...x \a@arg \a@c@last@ \a@last@line
\else \ifx \a@arg \a@c@put...   But i have tried it using sharelatex and it worked but i want to make it work uing texMaker too

Comment: can you please add more informations : version number of miktex, and arabtex. IMHO this is now another question so please ask new question.

Comment: i'm using : arabtex 3.17 ; Texmaker 4.5; miktex 2.9

Comment: for me: arabtex 3.11 ; Texmaker 4.5; miktex 2.9

Comment: so i don't have a problem with old software ... The problem is weird having two different output for the same text.

Comment: maybe you need to reinstall arabtex package.